# Svelte select issue where disabled value not binding on submit

Tags: forms, svelte, svelte-3

A Svelte select control that receives a value to match in a list from a rest api:

```
<script>
export let data;
export let name;
export let required;
export let disabled;

let options = [];

onMount(async () => { 
  options = await buildOptionsList ();
});

async function buildOptionsList () {
  let rv = [];
  try {
    let req = await fetch (....)
    req.data.forEach (item => {
      list.push ({
        value: item.value,
        text: item.text
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    ...
  }
  return rv;
}
</script>

<select class="form-control" {required} {disabled} name="{ name }" id="{ name }" 
    bind:value={data}>
    {#each options as option}
      <option value={option.value}>{ option.text }</option>
    {/each}
</select>
```

This all works ticketyboo, however, in certain cases (category of user) I need to make the select disabled.

In such cases, `data` appears correctly as the selected item in the list, and greyed out as the input is disabled; however on `submit` the relevant item in the form data is null.

How do I address this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` form fields are not sent. For `input` element that could be solved by using `readonly` instead, but `select` elements do not support this.

A common approach is to send a hidden field, something like:

```html
{#if disabled}
  <input type=hidden {name} value={data} />
{/if}
```

(Though if the field is disabled, the intention is probably that it cannot be changed by the user, so if the server actually uses that value, that is probably an error. You cannot trust data from the client to follow your rules.)

Comment: of course, thank you; some of my other badly written code had obscured this fact from me …